# Translate a <table> to <div>s

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<ul style="width: 300px; list-style-type:none">
    <li>
        <table style="width:100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" >
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"> 
                    <img src='..' width='60px' height='50px' />
                </td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-left:8px">
                    <p>Text here. Use all available left-over width, but stay in our own column. Expand content down vertically if required.</p>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img src='..' width='12px' height='12px' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to rewrite this using divs. Is it possible? I wanted to rewrite using divs in hopes that it'd be less html produced by my page, especially if I have like 100 li elements as above.

So the question is, can I get the same layout above, using just divs, and not a table?

Thanks

------------------------ Update ----------------

This is as close as I can get, but the col2 text will wrap under the col1 image if the text is too long. Is there a way to get it to just stay within the confines of its own column, or make the image in col1 block any content from going below it?:

```
<li>
  <img src='na' style='float:left; position:relative; width:70px; height:44px; display: block;' />
  <span style='float:right; background-color: crimson;'>x</span>
  <span style='display: block; font:14px; padding-left: 10px;'>Title which can be really long and obnoxious for formatting I suppose. Carry on more and more. You would think this would be really simple to do with divs.</span>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Exactly what parts of this design need to be replicated?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I'm just wondering if I can do the same thing by just using <div> elements?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  Tables aren't meant for layout in the first place (with the exception of tabular data).  CSS is made precisely to lay out your page.  There's some sample code provided, if you send us what you have now, perhaps we can get you over the hump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and I can't see the difference in Opera 10.6

```
    <li>
        <div id="cont" style="position:relative;">
            <div style="width: 60px; height: 50px;float: left;"><img src="" alt="Image" style="width:60px; height:50px;" /></div>
            <div style="padding-left:8px; float:left; width:220px;"><p>Text here. Use all available left-over width, but stay in our own column. Expand content down vertically if required.</p></div>
            <div style="width: 12px; height:12px; float:left;"><img src="" alt="image" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></div>
            <div style="clear:both" />
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould look at the css box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

I don't understund what you need, but i think that the HTML should be:

```
<p style="width: 300px">Text goes here, it will grow vertically if not enought horizontal space</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start... 
300px total
left col: 60px
right col: 12px
middle: 228px
fixed column widths

```
#wrapper {
text-align: left;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
border:0;
width: 300px;   
}

#header {
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
background: yellow;
}

#side-a {
float: left;
width: 60px;
}

#side-b {
float: right;
width: 12px;
}

#content { 
float: left;
width: 75%;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
background: #A2A2A2;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    HEADER
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="side-a">
        SIDE A
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div id="side-b">
        SIDE B
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Argh updated with as far as I got, still not 100% there though.

Comment: Where you at? What's missing?  If you use the code I pasted, the text from col 2 should never move into column one...